# Fourier Cosine Expansion of Piecewise Continuous Function

Tags: integration, fourier-series

Hi I am trying to represent this following function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 35.6236 + 0.161087e^{59.9842x},0\leq x < 0.1 \\
 35.6236 + 0.161087e^{59.9842 (-x + 0.2)},0.1\leq x \leq 0.2 \\
\end{cases} $$
In this form: 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_{n}\cos(n\pi x/L).$$
Obviously this is a Fourier Cosine series, so what I did was to find the even extension: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 35.6236 + 0.161087e^{-59.9842x},-0.1\leq x < 0 \\
 35.6236 + 0.161087e^{59.9842x},0\leq x \leq 0.1 \\
\end{cases} $$

And compute a normal Fourier Cosine Series:

$$p=2L$$
$$0.2=2L$$
$$L=\frac{1}{10}$$

Then:

$$C_0=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)dx$$

$$20 \left(\int_{-0.1}^0 (0.161087\exp(-59.9842 x)+35.6236) \, dx+\int_0^{0.1} (0.161087 \exp (59.9842 x)+35.6236)\,dx\right)$$

and finally: 
$$C_0=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)cos(\frac{nπx}{L})dx$$
$$=20 \left(\int_{-0.1}^0 (0.161087e^{-59.9842x}+35.6236)\cos (\pi  10 \unicode{0008} n x) \, dx+\int_0^{0.1} (0.161087e^{59.9842 x}+35.6236) \cos (\pi  10 \unicode{0008} n x) \, dx\right)$$

But when I graph this I don't get anything like the original function. Am I doing something wrong? Thank You.

Comment: You can't just use cosine to obtain a Fourier series, you'll need to include the sine terms as well. It's like trying to approximate $x$ if you're only allowed to use $1,x^2,x^4,x^6$... etc.